# Excel Filter function compare 2 arrays

Tags: microsoft-excel

Im trying to make a Filter function that compares values between selected columns and then returns the row.

If i add one colums it works fine like M23 but once i make it M23:M24 or anything else it fails.

This works

```
=FILTER(ALARM_W_A;  M21 = ALARM_W_A[aansluit_nr]; "No Result")
```

This doesnt

```
=FILTER(ALARM_W_A; M23:M25 ALARM_W_A[aansluit_nr]; "No Result")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the following formulas:

```
=LET(col; ALARM_W_A[aansluit_nr]; FILTER(ALARM_W_A; (M23=col)+(M24=col)+(M25=col); "No Result"))
=FILTER(ALARM_W_A; BYROWS(ALARM_W_A[aansluit_nr]; LAMBDA(a;OR(a=M23:M25))); "No result")
```